# Looping in a url or scrape data from variation in Url

Tags: python, loops, postman, scrape

My goal is to have all latitudes and longitude range for canada being automatically inputted into the code below and it scraping the locations that come up automatically. I know canada range is latitudes of 42°N to 83°N and longitude of 53°W to 141°W. I understand how to **scrape** this type of data but never had to loop information within a url.I have a fear I will  somehow make a loop that does nothing but get me ban from the website. So any help would be great!

```
import requests

url = "https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849&services=&region=global"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  'Referer': 'https://www.circlek.com/store-locator?Canada&lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'dnt': '1'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: you can use simple for loop  for making url for different location , bad case scenario which i suppose will not happen  but even if does then just search some free proxy server or vpn add to requests and you are ready again.

Comment: Do you have an example? Like where I would input that code. Would It go: for  url = then take the url and add the range for lat and long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented you can put your code like this , i am guessing your different latitude and longitude store in list like this if not share the range of lat_lng with difference

```
lat_lng = [(lat,long) for lat,long in zip(range(43,83),range(-141,-53))] #store or create range of latitude and longitude 

for latitude,longitude in lat_lng:
  url = f"https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&services=&region=global"
  payload={}
  headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.circlek.com/store-locator?Canada&lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'dnt': '1'
  }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

  print(response.json())
```

you wrap around in function also .

as you commented , for negative arrange `range` should be like this , it is working

```
lat_lng = [(lat,long) for lat,long in zip(range(43,83),range(-141,-53))]

#[(43, -141), (44, -140), (45, -139), (46, -138), (47, -137), (48, -136),.....]
```

In above output to have notice that in zip we have one to one like one latitude point to one longitude but if you want one to many see
[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module it will help.

for more accurate use i will suggest see [np.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) you can use for float also like

```
np.arange(43,83,0.001)
#array([43.   , 43.001, 43.002, ..., 82.997, 82.998, 82.999])
```

Comment: The range I want is : for lat: between 43.0000 and 83.0000 and for lng: -53.0000 and -141.0000. I don't mind going by 1 because duplicates are easy to take out in excel and parsing. I attempted to put the range in as  this:  lat_lng = [( (range (43.0000,83.0000)),(range(-53.0000,-141.0000)))]. However, my long shot of an attempt didnt work.

Comment: @John_Muir     I have edited some suggestion. it may help you.

Comment: I ran the: lat_lng = [(lat,long) for lat,long in zip(np.arange(43,83,0.001),np.arange(-141,-53,-0.001))] . It looks like it ran but nothing shows up in output screen. Just the blank >>>. Is maybe the servers not being able to return the data? or was it the way I inputted it not right ?

Comment: it is working fine see [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10dCqD-mL1JPIRsHN6X76AUEcMitx3wTU?usp=sharing)

Comment: yea going by change of 1 does work but it ends up missing a lot of the data. I wanted to use your method of using np.arange so it increase by factor of 0.001.