# Looping with small interval for lat and lng from a url request

Tags: loops, for-loop, parsing, web-scraping, latitude-longitude

So my code below seems to run fine but I get no output. The factor that makes it stop working is when I run arange with a 000.0001 interval. When I do a normal for range where it goes by 1 I get an output. My goal is to get back all the store locations of circle K and other convenience stores that the rename themselves in local regions of Canada. If anyone can point out the issue that would be great!

```
import requests
import json
import numpy as np
import csv 

lat_lng = [(lat,long) for lat,long in zip(np.arange(42,84,0.0001),np.arange(-142,-52,0.0001))] 

for latitude,longitude in lat_lng:
  url = f"https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&services=&region=global"
  payload={}
  headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.circlek.com/store-locator?Canada&lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'dnt': '1'
  }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

  print(response.json())
```

Comment: You may get better answers if you make part of your question what the expected outcome was and what happened instead. Were there suddenly zero iterations?

Comment: Learn about the previous step to this code in question, there is more material on site here: [Looping in a url or scrape data from variation in Url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68043817/367456)

Comment: Hey, hakre thanks for the link, helped explain a bit on looping. I realised how I made the negative mistake. It started running and now Im getting what I was originally aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sprung in my eye is that you're using a negative step for numpy.arange to express the distance between two adjacent values, `out[i+1] - out[i]`. as stop is after - and not before - a start, and as the interval does not include a stop value it does also not include this start value with this step.

this interval might appear flawed and the iterations then not working.

however as start is below stop and stop never is part, the range should be expected as what it is: empty.

as that range construes each tuples right hand side, there shouldn't be any tuples and therefore nothing to iterate over.

negating the step might turn this into a more expected result already.

Comment: I ended up taking out the minus in the longitude, this made the code start running. Can you clarify, does the range not include the original value?(in this case would include 43,53 in a (43,53,0.1))

Comment: you mean the start value? start is included, but not if it is lower than stop and the step is negative. see: [Counting Backwards](https://realpython.com/how-to-use-numpy-arange/#counting-backwards) and the following _Getting Empty Arrays_ section.